# How to build wardrobe with top shelf? Actual shelf, or two boxes?

Tags: carcass, construction

I am wanting to build a wardrobe with a shelf above the rail, but I am not sure how will be the appropriate way to go about it from the actual carcass construction to how to make the shelf itself.

I plan on making this wardrobe about 1600mm wide.

**Carcass (Internal shelf not included)**

I'm thinking of using 18mm melamine furniture board for the construction (I could be convinced to use MDF/plywood if given needed) and I'm of course not wanting to have any screw holes showing from the sides etc.

How should I go about this? I can see 3 options

1. Wardrobe sides within footprint of top/bottom and screw in from above/below
   [image]
2. Top/bottom within walls with screws through side - Can use plugs to cover screws etc
   [image]
3. Same again with top/bottom within walls but this time secured with pocket hole screws

**Internal shelf**

My main concern here is whether I should add a shelf inside of one, tall carcass; or whether I should make 2 carcasses - a box to sit on top of the main carcass with the join acting as the shelf.

If I were to go down the route of the former option... How would be best to do this? Considering that the 1600mm width of the wardrobe is quite a large span... Pocket holes, those little shelf pins?

Comment: 18mm chipboard/particleboard is significantly stronger than 12/13mm, but it's still a relatively weak material in span. And 1600mm is not an inconsiderable span! I was going to ask about your expected loads but it's been noted that it can sag *under its own weight*, so there's that.

Comment: Hmm.... I've seen that the wardrobes you can buy from the shop that are of these width are usually a combination of 1000 and 500. I'm just not 100% on the best way to go about it.

Comment: Yes, if you want a 1600mm span, you make 2 cabinets at 800mm each, or one at 1m and one at 600mm. Expecting particleboard to survive much weight over a 1600mm span without any additional support is, well, expecting too much. I have several 1000mm IKEA cabinets side-by-side with ~600mm ones to give me the space I need.

Comment: @Graphus - just a minor correction: particleboard absolutely WILL sag under its own weight, 100%  (unless it's less than 30cm / 12" wide) :)

Comment: @JanSpurny, yeah, given the expected type here I should have said will. The higher-density stuff is apparently much less subject to this than typical (I'm going by user reports exclusively here, never used it for shelf material myself).

Answer (score 3):

The traditional, and least visually disruptive to the exterior appearance of your wardrobe, would be to mount the shelf inside a full height carcass.   If you do this, though, you want the construction method to allow you to put the shelf in after the carcass is fully constructed and stabilized.   If there isn't any reason for the shelf to be adjustable, and given that you're using "thick" material for the carcass (rather than rail and stile framed panels, e.g.) I would do this by having rails to support the shelf on the three unexposed sides of the shelf, and putting the shelf on top of these.    The long rail along the back of the carcass then gives you support for the long dimension of the shelf, which at 1600mm will be quite valuable.   If you're using a composite material like particle board or mdf for the shelf, or if the shelf is more than 20cm or so wide, you should also screw a rail to the front of the shelf, to stiffen it.

THe side rails should be screwed to the carcass.   Counterbore and plug the screws if you really want them hidden, but for an interior piece, it's not reallyl necessary.   Traditionally, one does not attach long rails like that to the back of a carcass, which is usually much thinner material, and in the age when most things were solid wood, would typically have long grain horizontal on the back, leading to unacceptable movement of an attached rail, or more likely, to the back splitting.   But if you're using a composite material for the back, this isn't a big problem and you could attach the rail to the back.   Or, just attach it with screws to the back ends of the side rails.  20mm X 30mm rails (in cross section) would be a good choice.

Comment: I would also make the supporting rails out of wood, not MDF or particleboard. You need the long, connected grain of wood to support the weight of the shelf, which will be significant. I would also look into using thinner material than 18mm for the shelf to save some weight.

Comment: Be aware, though, @MattDMo, that thinner shelves will support less weight on top of them. Bit of a Catch-22, that particle board...

Comment: @FreeMan absolutely. However, going from 18mm down to 15 or 12 (I don't know what sizes are available) shouldn't cut the load capacity too much, but then again you may start to get sagging, unless the shelf is supported in the middle by a cross piece (or pieces) connecting the back cleat and the front rail. The best answer would be to use plywood for the shelf, of course.

Comment: @MattDMo:  Yes.  Thanks for adding that.  The rails should be solid wood, particularly the long rail across the back.